# Returning a mouse click event in a class NOT a form

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi

I've been stuck on Google these last 2 hours trying to find a way to return the fact that i click on my left mouse button.

How ever i cannot find anything to help me with this, all the people who's asked about something similar is using Forms. However that does not help me since i'm trying to get it in a Class.

Heres the code for it:

```
 private void MenuClick()
        {
            if (mousePosition.X >= 250 && mousePosition.X <= 500 && mousePosition.Y >= 100 && mousePosition.Y <= 150)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Mouse Clicked");
            }
    }
```

I've tried MouseButtons.left = True. But it keeps telling me that the left side of it should always be a properthy, variable or indexer.. And last i checked Bool is a variable...

Any help on this?

(Ps. The current code i have works. It just works on mouseover instead of when i click.)

Comment: Post the code you attempted.  Post the subscription to the event, the event delegant, ect.

Answer (score 3):

`...should always be a property, variable or indexer...` most likely means that you're using an assignment operator `=` instead of a comparison operator `==`.  Also, `MouseButtons` is an enumeration, not a boolean, thus you should be doing something like the following:

```
e.Button == MouseButtons.Left
```

Keep in mind, e.Button won't be available unless you are capturing the click event inside of an event that passes in the state of the mouse in `e`.  For instance, if you capture the MouseDown event on the form itself, you'd handle it in the following manner:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Left Clicked.");
    }
    else if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Right Clicked.");
    }
}
```

Comment: But that will only work in a Form right? I am not working in the background code of a Form, i am working in a class. That's where i need it as well.

Comment: Yep it doesent work. The game we are working on creates the entire game world from the class called "GameWorld.cs" Were as the only thing we use our form is to get the Gameloop. (The timer_tick)